# Android - searching music using MediaStore using a string

Tags: android

I basically can not accomplish this for over 2 weeks now.

I have posted a numerous amount of code over a few questions yet most of them got ignored so I won't flood this question with more code of my own that won't even be read.

How do I search the MediaStore with "LIKE" attributes using a String?

E.G. I type in Shoot To Thrill, I receive song ID with this code:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                        test.setText(title +" " + artist + " " + id);
                    }
                }
```

Here is something to begin with:

```
String[] projection = {
                            BaseColumns._ID,    
                            MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
                }

Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, //uri
                        projection, //projection
                        //i dont know what to enter,
                        //i dont know what to enter,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just normal SQL hiding behind the scenes. Normal LIKE operations should work just fine. You can use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE \"%thrill%\""` just like any other SQL query.

```
String[] projection = { BaseColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE };

String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ?";
String[] params = new String[] { "%life%" };

Cursor q = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection, where, params, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

try {
    while (q.moveToNext()) {
        Log.e("song", q.getString(1) + " " + q.getString(2));
    }
} finally {
    q.close();
}
```

Comment: This is a very basic question but I severely struggle with SQL.. would you mind telling me what do the selection and selectionArgs do?(where and params in this case) like, how do they affect the search process?

Comment: `where` becomes the [WHERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_\(SQL\)) clause in the SQL query. `params` replaces every question mark in the WHERE clause with an escaped value so you don't have to worry about quoting. [Wikipedia has some more in-depth info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_\(SQL\)).

Comment: do u know how i can ignore some text??suppose i have to sort songs and ignore the word "the" while sorting???